Out of given opcua nodes some node are temporarily unavailable for subscription. How to get data change notification once node is back online?
Suppose 3 nodes to be subscribed for data change (which get automatically stored in the self._monitored_items()dictionary provided by asyncua) in this case if any of the nodes become unavailable for sometime and then becomes available again then how does the client know that node is back online ?
 async with client:
        # We create a Client Subscription.
            subscription = await client.create_subscription(50, handler)
            nodes = [
                client.get_node('ns=3;i=1025'),
                client.get_node('ns=3;i=1026'),
                client.get_node('ns=3;i=1027')
            ]
            handle = await subscription.subscribe_data_change(nodes)

            print(subscription._monitored_items)

I tried with read_value method which checks the value of each node periodically and if we get value that means the node is available..... but the problem here is that if my checking period is of 10 seconds and the node becomes available in first 2 sec the 8 seconds data is lost.
async def check_node_availability(node):
        """ Check if the node is still available on the server by reading its value. """
        try:
            await node.read_value()
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            # print(f'Failed to read node {node}: {e}')
            return False

How to prevent this data loss mentioned above?

An OPC UA Client should not need to care about this.
The OPC UA Server should report a Bad_NodeIdUnknown status when the monitored node disappears and should automatically continue to report values when the node re-appears.
The Subscription and MonitoredItem can stay alive the whole time and no data should be lost.
If the server does not behave like this, then have a look if the server supports ModelChangeEvents.
A server can report ModelChangeEvents when nodes or references appear or disappear.
A Client can subscribe for the ModelChangeEvent and receive the information which nodes have changed.
As for any event Subscription, Events can be subscribed on any event propagating node, e.g. a parent object, a folder or on the "Server" node to receive all events.
If none of the previous ways work, then the cyclic read seems to be the only solution.

Can we check the status of the monitored items directly?

@MeetBedmutha There is no OPC UA service for that, but your client or client SDK could cache this information. I am not familiar with this python SDK.

Is there any method without cyclic read and event which will let us know if the node is active/inactive?

@MeetBedmutha Not really you could use other services for the cyclic check like Browse or TranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds, but there is not much difference to the cyclic read. Subscription for data changes or events is the only Client-Server feature to get automatic value updates.

Tried Change Event but is not providing changes although nodes added and removed Event Notification: Event(['Changes:None', "EventId:b'29030d10c0d3438ba0db9529a44b90c1'", 'EventType:NodeId(Identifier=2133, NamespaceIndex=0, NodeIdType=<NodeIdType.FourByte: 1>)', 'SourceNode:NodeId(Identifier=1, NamespaceIndex=2, NodeIdType=<NodeIdType.FourByte: 1>)', 'SourceName:MyObject', 'Time:2024-11-29 09:52:09.842259+00:00', 'ReceiveTime:2024-11-29 09:52:09.842259+00:00', 'LocalTime:TimeZoneDataType(Offset=330, DaylightSavingInOffset=True)', 'Message:LocalizedText(Locale=None, Text=None)', 'Severity:1'])

@MeetBedmutha For events you need to set the select clause for the fields you want. You want the contents of the "Changes" field. See https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part5/v104/docs/6.4.32 and https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part5/v104/docs/12.16

Changes field is giving output as None after applying select clause.
